# Hide table headers of table when mobile responsive

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am working with jQuery Datatables and I have created the table for the same. I have a task for making it mobile responsive which I did it. But I want to hide the table headers completely when I view the table in mobile view and it should be back to normal like headers should be displayed when on normal screen.

To be more specific I am able to hide the headers normally using css but when I enable the vertical scrolling to my table my headers become visible in mobile view which I don't want.

Example table code. Data is repeated for testing.

```
<table id="no-more-tables">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th class="numeric">Price</th>
        <th class="numeric">Change</th>
        <th class="numeric">Change %</th>
        <th class="numeric">Open</th>
        <th class="numeric">High</th>
        <th class="numeric">Low</th>
        <th class="numeric">Volume</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
        <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.     </td>
        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
        <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.     </td>
        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
        <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.     </td>
        <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
        <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
        <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="High" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
        <td data-title="Low" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
        <td data-title="Volume" class="numeric">9,395</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and the css for the same is:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
#no-more-tables table, 
#no-more-tables thead, 
#no-more-tables tbody, 
#no-more-tables th, 
#no-more-tables td, 
#no-more-tables tr { 
    display: block; 
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
#no-more-tables thead tr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

#no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

#no-more-tables td { 
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
    white-space: normal;
    text-align:left;
}

#no-more-tables td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*
Label the data
*/
#no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
</style>
```

The jQuery code for converting table to datatable:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#no-more-tables').DataTable({
"bSort" : false,
"paging" : false,
"info" : false,
"searching" : false,
"bProcessing" : true,
"scrollY":"400px",
"scrollCollapse": true,
"scrollX": false
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: check this url and full code it may useful  : http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2016/12/create-simple-and-perfect-responsive.html

Comment: hey..i checked the url u gave me..and i m using the exact method to make my table responsive..but when i add a scroll-Y option for vertical scrolling by headers become visible which i dont want...plz help.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for you guidance..please find the above code as reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using datatable, so it is changing the dom.
So in css replace #no-more-tables with #no-more-tables_wrapper.
And your code will work. Please check and confirm

Comment: i tried display:none; in media queries..but did not work.

Comment: please add, how you are enable vertical scrolling

Comment: "scrollY":"400px",
"scrollCollapse": true,